# Eclipse Indigo crashes on startup after Google plugin and GWT installation

Tags: eclipse, gwt, plugins, crash

I am running on a Mac OS X 10.5.8.

I made an earlier post about GPE/GWT not working for Eclipse 4.2. So I tried with Eclipse 3.7.2 instead. This time, I installed GPE 3.7 and GWT 2.4 plugins. Again, the installation was successful and it asked me to restart Eclipse SDK when it was finished.

After selecting my workspace and it starts up, it would crash shortly afterwards with a pop-up error. The error messages say "Error notifying registry change listener \
Invalid registry object". The workbench would close immediately after the pop-up error.

I can restore the workbench to a working state if I remove the Google plugin from the plugins folder.

I tried different Eclipse Indigo packages, the S2 Eclipse IDE for Java Developers and the Java EE, both encountered the exact same scenario after I installed GPE 3.7 and GWT 2.4 plugins.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try asking your question in the [GPE Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-plugin-eclipse) - you might have a higher chance of it being addressed.

Comment: Yes. Turns out my Mac was 64bit. Download the 64bit version of eclipse. Case closed.